# ubuntu svn post commit hook does not work, but works on manual running

Tags: svn, ubuntu, post-commit

```
/usr/bin/svn update /var/project2_test/debug --username XXXX--password XXXX
/bin/echo $REV >> /var/project2_test/svn.log
```

the log has been updated while committing. but working copy never update.
And I run /home/admin/svn/project/hooks/post-commit by hand. IT WORKS!

Answer (score 0):

1. Post-commit hook (any hook really)

   - running in empty environment
   - running under another user credentials, than on running by hand (user of SVN-server used)
2. Anyway, you have to debug hook's script under real conditions (as hook). In orderto do it, you have

   - Intercept output of `update` command (by redirecting stdout to stderr)
   - Show this output to user, which perform commit, i.e, because stderr marshalled to user only in case of error in hook, you have to exit hook with non-zero exit-code

Hook in debug-stage will be something like

```
/usr/bin/svn update /var/project2_test/debug --username XXXX --password XXXX > &2
/bin/echo $REV >> /var/project2_test/svn.log
exit 1
```

Comment: how to use this script in debug-stage? i am a green on linux. more specific, please.

Comment: @user2724902 - use "as is" and read carefully output of hook in responce